# EDI to XML Huge file conversions

Tags: java, xml, out-of-memory, heap-memory, edi

I am converting an EDI file to XML. However my input file which happens to also be in BIF is approximately 100Mb is giving me a JAVA out of memory error.

I tried to consult Smook's Documentation for the huge file conversion, however it is a conversion from XML to EDI.

Below is the response I am getting when running my main

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127)
        at freemarker.core.TextBlock.accept(TextBlock.java:56)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:257)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:57)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:278)
        at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:157)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:501)
        at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:67)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:257)
        at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:173)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:686)
        at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:80)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:257)
        at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:57)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:257)
        at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:235)
        at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:262)
        at org.milyn.util.FreeMarkerTemplate.apply(FreeMarkerTemplate.java:92)
        at org.milyn.util.FreeMarkerTemplate.apply(FreeMarkerTemplate.java:86)
        at org.milyn.event.report.HtmlReportGenerator.applyTemplate(HtmlReportGenerator.java:76)
        at org.milyn.event.report.AbstractReportGenerator.processFinishEvent(AbstractReportGenerator.java:197)
        at org.milyn.event.report.AbstractReportGenerator.processLifecycleEvent(AbstractReportGenerator.java:157)
        at org.milyn.event.report.AbstractReportGenerator.onEvent(AbstractReportGenerator.java:92)
        at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:558)
        at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)
        at com.***.xfunctional.EdiToXml.runSmooksTransform(EdiToXml.java:40)
        at com.***.xfunctional.EdiToXml.main(EdiToXml.java:57)

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.milyn.Smooks;
import org.milyn.SmooksException;
import org.milyn.container.ExecutionContext;
import org.milyn.event.report.HtmlReportGenerator;
import org.milyn.io.StreamUtils;
import org.milyn.payload.StringResult;
import org.milyn.payload.SystemOutResult;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class EdiToXml {

  private static byte[] messageIn = readInputMessage();

  protected static String runSmooksTransform() throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {

    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    // Instantiate Smooks with the config...
    Smooks smooks = new Smooks("smooks-config.xml");
    try {
      // Create an exec context - no profiles....
      ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();

      StringResult result = new StringResult();

      // Configure the execution context to generate a report...
      executionContext.setEventListener(new HtmlReportGenerator("target/report/report.html"));

      // Filter the input message to the outputWriter, using the execution context...
      smooks.filterSource(executionContext, new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(messageIn)),result);

      Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);

      return result.getResult();
    } finally {
      smooks.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, SmooksException {
    System.out.println("\n\n==============Message In==============");
    System.out.println("======================================\n");

    pause(
        "The EDI input stream can be seen above.  Press 'enter' to see this stream transformed into XML...");

    String messageOut = EdiToXml.runSmooksTransform();

    System.out.println("==============Message Out=============");
    System.out.println(messageOut);
    System.out.println("======================================\n\n");

    pause("And that's it!  Press 'enter' to finish...");
  }

  private static byte[] readInputMessage() {
    try {
      InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/****/Downloads/BifInputFile.DATA"));
      return StreamUtils.readStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "<no-message/>".getBytes();
    }
  }

  private static void pause(String message) {
    try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.print("> " + message);
      in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
  }

}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:edi="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/edi-1.4.xsd">
  <!--
     Configure the EDI Reader to parse the message stream into a stream of SAX events.
     -->
  <edi:reader mappingModel="edi-to-xml-bif-mapping.xml" validate="false"/>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

I edited this line in the code to reflect the usage of a stream :-

```
smooks.filterSource(executionContext, new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("/home/***/Downloads/sample-text-file.txt")), result);
```

However I now have this below as error. Anybody any guess what is the best approach ?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)
    at ****.EdiToXml.runSmooksTransform(EdiToXml.java:41)
    at com.***.***.EdiToXml.main(EdiToXml.java:58)
Caused by: org.milyn.edisax.EDIParseException: EDI message processing failed [EDIFACT-BIF-TO-XML][1.0].  Must be a minimum of 1 instances of segment [UNH].  Currently at segment number 1.
    at org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapSegments(EDIParser.java:504)
    at org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.mapSegments(EDIParser.java:453)
    at org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.parse(EDIParser.java:428)
    at org.milyn.edisax.EDIParser.parse(EDIParser.java:386)
    at org.milyn.smooks.edi.EDIReader.parse(EDIReader.java:111)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:76)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: All we can tell you is that it looks as if the utility you are using for the conversion puts the entire document in memory and is therefore going to have a limit on the size of input it can handle. Get more memory, or rethink your approach from scratch.

Comment: Is it one document?  Or multiple documents in the interchange?  Wondering if you could split by message in the interchange...

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, somebody as well advised me same, I tried reading the input file per limited amounts of byte, however it happens at time there is no UNT found in the current byte being read, so it fails ...

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure if I understood well, but lets say its like a list of objects ... in your understanding we would replace the term object by document.

Comment: *Caused by: org.milyn.edisax.EDIParseException: EDI message processing failed [EDIFACT-BIF-TO-XML][1.0].  Must be a minimum of 1 instances of segment [UNH].  Currently at segment number 1.* Looks like you might have badly-formed input

Comment: You should be a bit more precise on what kind of data you have. Especially in the EDI domain there are lots of different styles and even within EDIFACT itself you have i.e. the EANCOM "slang". In the case of EDIFACT i.e. you see what kind of message you're dealing in the UNH message header which could contain something like `UNH+1+INVOIC:D:01B:UN` for a plain invoice that follows the UN/ECE recommendation draft published in the second half of 2001. Your input file seems to clearly miss out on such a mandatory definition and thus is not a valid EDIFACT file

Comment: ... But why do you even need to convert that input file to XML? Do you want to validate it against the official specification?

Comment: @g00se I tested the file and XML mapping using only 1 document (data between a UNH & a UNT) it worked. To be more specific, when I read the whole file into an array of Bytes I get just the Out of Memory Error but when with InputStream it gives me this error. Do you think when reading chunks it  might happen that some of the chunks are reading without UNH ? Because it has not been instructed that every chunk must atleast contain 1 UNH & UNT inclusive of everything in between ? Thanks for potentially any input on that.

Comment: @RomanVottner Can you elaborate please ? Yes its quite foolish because the aim is to later store the data into a database. But at the moment it would also be useful to have them in XML, but I am very interested in knowing what do you mean. Thanks for potentially any input.

Comment: I can only comment on the basis of first principles. Number one, I have no knowledge of the document types and number two, I have no no knowledge of what the parser/reader is actually doing. Using DOM parsing is impossible because of your memory constraints so it will be using stream or SAX-based parsing. Therefore it's not going to be easy for it to check for well-formedness or validity. It must do at some point for you to get errors relating to validity though.

Comment: @g00se EDIFACT, while having a certain tree-structure under the hood, itself is a flat-text format which separates segmetns usually via a `'` character, elements within a segment via the `+` character and respective components in complex elements via `:` character. These characters may be redefined using an optional leading `UNA` segment though. [1/3]

Comment: @g00se So, basically the simplest form of parsing would split the segments using the defined or default segment terminator, looking up the position in the "tree" using the message structure definition for that message type, i.e. [PRICAT](https://service.unece.org/trade/untdid/d01b/trmd/pricat_c.htm) or [INVOIC](https://service.unece.org/trade/untdid/d01b/trmd/invoic_c.htm), and then coordinate further (complex) element parsing to its element sub-components and so forth. [2/3]

Comment: @g00se Problem here is though that there are different charsets to consider (i.e. `UNOA`, `UNOC`, `UNOW`, ...), different message version (1, 2, 3, 4) that influence what (complex) elements there may be for service segments such as `UNB`, `UNH`, ..., as well as different directory versions (i.e. `D:01B`, `D:96A`, `S:19B`, ...) which define the overall message structure and (complex) elements. Beside that you also have an `EANCOM` slang administered by GS1 (the ones who issues the bar codes i.e.) which define their own stuff on top of EDIFACT [3/3]

Comment: Right. Good luck with validating that if you're a validator builder ;)

Comment: @g00se I already did that, twice. [ts-edifact](https://github.com/RovoMe/ts-edifact) which is a bit outdated and not conformant to the actual specification and a yet-closed-source Java implementation that only uses Smooks to load the actual directory definitions which I use to generate intermediary JSON files that are used during validation and tree build time. Both implementations are able to rebuild the tree-structure of the Edifact file, though only the Java based version can output an XML representation which is though not streamed yet and thus may suffer from memory/performance footprints

Comment: Hi all, the message input was good and the xml mapping was good as well. I found out from where the mistake was coming. posting an answer shortly for the comunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message was valid and the xml mapping was good. I was just not using the optimal method for message reading and writing.

I came to realize the filterSource method of Smooks can directly be fed with an InputStream & OutputStream as variables. Kindly find below the piece of code that led to an efficient running of the program without going through JAVA memory error.

```
//Instantiate a FileInputStream
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);

//Instantiate an FileOutputStream
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);


try {    

  // Filter the input message to the outputWriter...
  smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource(inputStream), new StreamResult(outputStream));

  Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);

} finally {
  smooks.close();
  inputStream.close();
  outputStream.close();
}
```

Thanks to the community.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the original author of Smooks and that Edifact parsing stuff. Jason emailed me asking for advice on this but I haven't been involved in it for a number of years now, so not sure how helpful I’d be.

Smooks doesn’t read the full message into memory. It streams it though a parser that converts it to a stream of SAX events, making it “look like” XML to anything downstream of it. If those events are then used to build a big Java object model in men then that might result in OOM errors etc.

Looking at the Exception message, it simply looks like the EDIFACT input doesn’t match the definition file being used.

```
Caused by: org.milyn.edisax.EDIParseException: EDI message processing failed [EDIFACT-BIF-TO-XML][1.0].  Must be a minimum of 1 instances of segment [UNH].  Currently at segment number 1.
```

Those EDIFACT definition files were originally generated directly from the definitions published by the EDIFACT group, but I do remember that many people “tweak” the message formats, which seems like what might be happening here (and hence the above error). One solution to that would be to tweak the pre-generated definitions to match.

I know that a lot of changes have been made in Smooks in this area in the last year or two (using Apache Daffodil for the definitions) but I wouldn’t be the best person to talk about that. You can try the Smooks mailing list for help on that.